# numpy meshgrid and plot resize

Tags: python, numpy, plot, polygon, kml

I want plot polygon from kml file into meshgrid
my code is the following :

```
from fastkml import kml
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("file.kml", "rt") as fichier:
        doc = fichier.read().encode("utf-8")
        k = kml.KML()
        k.from_string(doc)
        features = list(k.features())
        f1 = list(features[0].features())
        print(f1[0])
        polygone_Z = f1[0].geometry
        x,y = polygone_Z.exterior.xy
        print(x,y)
xvalues = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]);
yvalues = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]);
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xvalues, yvalues)
plt.title('IIC')
plt.grid()

plt.plot(xx, yy, marker='.', color='k', linestyle='none')

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

this is the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcdTo.jpg)

and this when I zoome in to show polygon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFSso.png)

my question is how can I resize my polygone to be shown clearly at meshgrid

NB : ploygone geometry is : POLYGON Z ((1.418025088521837 23.824589593292842 0, 1.4274020912379015 23.825979577617314 0, 1.439547133657335 23.80592457540161 0, 1.4297838928431261 23.802335549155444 0, 1.4187331917017687 23.815551264993776 0, 1.4227028610438097 23.819304327195326 0, 1.418025088521837 23.824589593292842 0))

Comment: I guess what you want is to adjust the grid not the polygon...   if you use something like `xvalues = np.linspace(1, 2, 100),  yvalues=np.linspace(23, 24, 100)` you should get a better result...

Comment: okey thanks but still appear in little size add to that i must keept grid point integers because i need simulate a digital grid

Comment: Well, if `x` and `y` are numpy arrays you can just scale and shift them.